# Where did the name Jesus come from?

Tags: life-of-jesus

The name Immanuel is the name of prophecy,( Isaiah 7:14 KJV)"... Behold, a virgin shall conceive, and bear a son, and shall call his NAME Immanuel." This was told to Joseph again in Matthew 1:22-23. Consider this, if Jesus is the name of our Messiah, we are to believe that the following is true:

The birth of the Messiah and his name Immanuel was prophesied 350 years before he was born, Joseph was told the name Immanuel again, in Matt 1:22-23, they then turn around and name him Jesus? Jesus a name that was not prophesied. An unknown name versus the name they and all of Israel knew for 350 years! Immanuel is the name given to Isaiah by our heavenly Father then given again to Joseph by angelic messenger. Then Joseph and Mary defy the words of our heavenly Father both in the 350 year old prophecy and by angelic messenger, ignore it and name the promised child Jesus? Not only that, we are to believe that our heavenly Father allowed his words and desires to go unfulfilled? Jesus is a name not prophesied but inserted by unscrupulous bible translators. Examine Matthew Chapter 1 to see the trickery, they insert Jesus at the very beginning, use it throughout, then give you the actual truth in verses 22-23.

Our Messiah's name is Immanuel, not Jesus, we have been lied to when we are told Immanuel is a TITLE so we accept the false name of Jesus. Immanuel is the NAME given to his son, our Messiah, by our heavenly Father and told to Isaiah.     Immanuel is the name of prophecy where did the name Jesus come from? What our Father states comes true to the smallest detail.Isaiah 55:11. The name Jesus is NOT the fulfillment of the prophecy in Isaiah 7:14,it is a false name.

All of Israel, including Mary and Joseph, knew the prophecy for 350 years they did not know the name Jesus, or the so called Hebrew versions of it Yeshua, Yahushua, Yahawashi these names were never prophesied or mentioned 350 years before his birth, not until cunning bible translators inserted Jesus in the beginning of Matthew and through out the entire New Testament to mislead and fool the masses that we know the name Jesus. Just as Jeremiah 16:19 states we have inherited lies! Confirm what is stated in this comment with prayer. Our heavenly Father teaches his sheep not men or religions. In fulfillment of the words in Revelation 12:9, Satan is deceiving the entire earth, with lies inserted in the scriptures, 40,000 Christian sects, and much more. Finally I ask Immanuel is the name of prophecy where is the prophecy telling us the name of Jesus? Where did the name Jesus come from?

Comment: Are you thinking the whole new testament is false because the name given to the child was Jesus (Joshua--Jehovah is salvation), rather than Immanuel (God with us)?  Are you still looking for a Messiah?

Comment: Apparently, Christians were able to figure out Immanuel being their Messiah.  [Have a listen](https://www.bing.com/videos/search?q=Medieval+Chant+O+Come+Emmanuel&adlt=STRICT&view=detail&mid=DC454B93776760787395DC454B93776760787395&&FORM=VRDGAR)

Comment: Immanuel was probably more of a Title, but more and likely it is because Immanuel and Jesus (in which can be salvation) have a similar context: a God/Saviour. He is refered to (and think at some point refers to himself as Immanuel, but I am unsure) as Immanuel by his followers.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple **titles** given for the Messiah in Isaiah, not just Immanuel ('God with us'). The most notable other prophetic name is 'Pele-joez-el-gibbor-abi-ad-sar-shalom' (translated something like 'Almighty God, Everlasting Father, Prince of Peace'), found in Isaiah 9:6. Moreover, the Hebrew word שְׁמ֖וֹ ('shemo'), as found in the Westminster Leningrad Codex, is translated often as 'name', but also carries with it connotations of renown, or alternatively used to refer to titles, divine or otherwise (according to Strong's). So it is perfectly reasonable that Immanuel is *a title* used for the Messiah, as much as (if not more so than) it could be *a name.*

As for the transliteration/translation point - the figure we call Jesus gets his English name from the Greek Ἰησοῦς (Iesous) via Latin Iesus. Ἰησοῦς is the Greek form of ישוע (Yeshua, 'God is deliverance'), a variant form of יְהוֹשֻׁעַ ('Yehoshua', meaning the same), which we often transliterate as 'Joshua'.  Jesus of Nazareth and Joshua, the assistant of Moses (who was born הוֹשֵׁעַ, 'Hoshe'a', meaning 'salvation') had variations of the same name (like people called Bill and William).

Indeed in Greek translations of the Old Testament, Joshua son of Nun is called 'Ἰησοῦς τοῦ Ναυή" ('Iesous tou Naue', 'Jesus son of Naue (Nun's name in Greek)'); all other Joshuas in the Septuagint are also Jesuses, with other descriptors added. We can be fairly sure that Jesus was the name given by Mary (who, incidentally in Aramaic is actually Mariam (מרים)) and Joseph to the baby (itself an apt name), and the *titles given in Isaiah and other prophetic literature indeed honorifics*, much like the names 'Messiah' and (in particular) 'Christ' (both meaning 'anointed' in Hebrew and Greek respectively) are used similarly.

I'm not any sort of exegete, but just someone who likes languages and finds the good book interesting. Hope this helps!

As a coda: reference to the name 'Jesus' in Matthew 1:21 (KJV):

> And she shall bring forth a son, and thou shalt call his name Jesus: for he shall save his people from their sins.

And in the 1550 Stephanus New Testament in Koine Greek:

> τεξεται δε υιον και καλεσεις το ονομα αυτου **ιησουν** αυτος γαρ σωσει τον λαον αυτου απο των αμαρτιων αυτων

There's a form of Ἰησοῦς again.

Comment: There's also a parallel account of Matthew 1:21 at Luke 1:31. Luke 2:21 confirms their obedience in giving the name that the angel said.